# \thanks{} footnote indented when using amsart and doc

Tags: footnotes, indentation, documentation, amsart

When using the `amsart` document class in combination with the `doc` package, I get an extra indent in the `thanks` footnote of the first author:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{doc}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{first author}
\thanks{thanks1}
\author{second author}
\thanks{thanks2}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: crop of footnote of complication]

Is there any way to circumvent this behaviour?

Comment: quick analysis -- the `doc` package redefines `\maketitle` and within it, it redefines `\@makefnmark`, overwriting the redefinition for the "adminiatrative footnotes" in `amsart`.  i'm trying to find a concise workaround that doesn't destroy the other things that `doc` is intended to do.  (the top matter is handled quite differently in ams document classes than in the basic latex classes.  `doc` is designed to be used with the basic classes.  i'm not surprised at this incompatibility, and there may well be more not yet discovered.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update of `\@setthanks` seems to suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{doc}

\makeatletter
\def\@setthanks{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\def\thanks##1{\@par##1\@addpunct.}\thankses}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\author{first author}
\thanks{thanks1}
\author{second author}
\thanks{thanks2}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[`amsart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart) mentions

> In order to make multiple thanks footnotes work inside a single
>   `\@footnotetext` argument we need to make the first `\par` be
>   ignored. Cf. `\@setthanks`.

and then sets `\def\par{\let\par\@par}` as the first thing in `\@footnotetext`. So, using `\@par` from the start with every `\thanks` introduces the vertical skip which is reverted using `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`.

Comment: Ah, this seems to be what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

patch the portions of the `\maketitle` command in `doc.sty` that set the footnote
indentation to use the values from `amsart`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{doc}
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {\parindent 1em}{\parindent\normalparindent}%
  {}{}
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {\hbox to1.8em}{\hbox to\normalparindent}%
  {}{}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{first author}
\thanks{thanks1}
\author{second author}
\thanks{thanks2}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the `\patchcmd` version of @patrick-happel's solution, right? Also very nice, thank you.

Comment: @Jonathan -- yes, this is equivalent to the solution you refer to.  either of these solutions would likely be acceptable in an article submitted to the ams for publication.  i've never seen a submission using the `doc` package, but `doc` isn't on the ams list of "discouraged" or incompatible packages.

Comment: thank you for the information! The reason for this (unconventional) combination is that I used the `doc` package to document some code related to an article writen in `amsart` and I wanted the code documentation to be in the same format as the article .... Everything else seems to have worked fine out of the box, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could for example change the definition of `\@makefntext` in the definition of `\maketitle` by the `doc` package.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{doc}
\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{\par
      \begingroup
        \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
      \setcounter{footnote}\z@
      \def\@makefnmark{\hbox to\z@{$\m@th^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}%
      \long\def\@makefntext##1{\noindent
          \ifnum\c@footnote>\z@\relax
            \hbox to1.8em{\hss$\m@th^{\@thefnmark}$}##1%
          \else
          \hbox to1.8em{\hfill}%
            \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-1.8em}{\raggedright ##1}%
          \fi}
      \if@twocolumn\twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \else\newpage\global\@topnum\z@\@maketitle\fi
      \thispagestyle{titlepage}\@thanks\endgroup
      \setcounter{footnote}\z@
      \gdef\@date{\today}\gdef\@thanks{}%
      \gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}}


\makeatother
\begin{document}
\title{title\footnote{A footnote}\footnote{Another footnote}}
\author{first author}
\thanks{thanks1}
\author{second author}
\thanks{thanks2}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, this works but doesn't seem "better" than just copying the `amsart` definition of `\maketitle`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `doc` package redefines `\maketitle`, the main purpose seems to be allowing several titles in one document: The [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/doc) says

> For the same reason the `\maketitle` command is slightly changed to
>   allow multiple titles in one document. So you can make one driver file
>   reading in several articles at once. To avoid an unwanted pagestyle on
>   the title page the `\maketitle` command issues a
>   `\thispagestyle{titlepage}` declaration which produces a plain page if
>   the titlepage page style is undefined.

The simple solution is to just redefine `\maketitle` with the `amsart` definition:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{doc}
% doc package redefines \maketitle, this is taken from amsart.cls
\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{\par
  \@topnum\z@ % this prevents figures from falling at the top of page 1
  \@setcopyright
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}% this sets first page specifications
  \uppercasenonmath\shorttitle
  \ifx\@empty\shortauthors \let\shortauthors\shorttitle
  \else \andify\shortauthors
  \fi
  \@maketitle@hook
  \begingroup
  \@maketitle
  \toks@\@xp{\shortauthors}\@temptokena\@xp{\shorttitle}%
  \toks4{\def\\{ \ignorespaces}}% defend against questionable usage
  \edef\@tempa{%
    \@nx\markboth{\the\toks4
      \@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}{\the\@temptokena}}%
  \@tempa
  \endgroup
  \c@footnote\z@
  \@cleartopmattertags
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{first author}
\thanks{thanks1}
\author{second author}
\thanks{thanks2}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Compiles to yield

[image: crop of footnotes in compiled document]

as required.

However, I expect there is some "cleaner" version, in particular in case anyone is interested in using the extra features of the `doc` version of `\maketitle`...

Comment: the ams document classes are each designed to handle only a single titled document; collections and proceedings volumes published by the ams are "combined" separately after pdf output of the separate parts has been produced.  trying to modify that approach, i'm afraid, sends one into the area of "beyond this place be dragons".

Answer (score 1):

All the answers correct the `\maketitle` made by `doc` package. Although IMO this is the logical/right approach, a solution with `\makeatletter ...` stuffs is not easy to remember. So my solution is make a fake thanks with a simple footnotes without marks **after** `\maketitle`. Surely someone will find this a bad practice, but far I can see this do not break anything in this way:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{doc}
\def\thanks#1{{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{#1.}\setcounter{footnote}{0}}}
\begin{document}
\author{first author}
\author{second author}
\title{title}
\maketitle
\thanks{thanks1}
\thanks{thanks2}
Some  text\footnote{A normal footnote.}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Ah, this is also a very elegant solution, I really like the idea :)

Comment: provided this isn't to be submitted for publication to the ams, it *appears* to work.  the ams style requires that `\thanks`es be input just after the `\author` entries to which they refer, and they are then properly set by `\maketitle`.  if `\thanks` defined in this way is moved back into its "required" position in the input, these footnotes will print out on a page by themselves, and the article will start on a new page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton of course, I remarked in bold that must be after `\maketitle` for this reason. On the other side, if `doc` package is used to have multiple titles with different  `\thanks` (maybe I assumed that was not for editor's eyes thinking about this problem) the original command could be a little disappointing.